# How to match username with encrypted password on login (java)

Tags: java, authentication, passwords, encryption

I have stored username and encrypted password in oracle DB. How I will match the username with 
encrypted password on login?

For example: username = abcd, encrypted password = #a11jsuy*&^ (actual password = abcd). When user want to login at that time he will use username = abcd and password = abcd. But the DB stores encrypted password = #a11jsuy*&^. How to match the password with encrypted password and with the username to login?

I am using java and JSF. Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance.

I'm using following code:

```
FUNCTION get_hash (p_loginname  IN  VARCHAR2,
                     p_password  IN  VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

l_salt VARCHAR2(30) := 'PutYourSaltHere';

  BEGIN
    -- Pre Oracle 10g
    RETURN DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(
      input_string => p_loginname || l_salt || UPPER(p_password));

  END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to match the *pre-encrypted* password.  Your database stores the encrypted version, so you can take the password the user inputs, encrypt it, and then see if it matches the value in your database.

Comment: Some algorithms give different results to the same text, so this method will not be useful in those cases. It is not good practice to encrypt passwords, they must be hashed.

Answer (score 3):

If it's really *encrypted*, take the password from the database, decrypt it, and compare this decrypted password with the one provided by the user.

If, as it should be, it's actually *hashed*, then take the password provided by the user, hash it, and compare the result with the hashed password stored in the database.

Of course, the algorithm used to decrypt/hash the password must be the same as the one used when storing the password in the database.

Comment: What happens to the user name is not clear. You first check the password and then check for username?

Comment: No. You apply the same hashing algorithm (`get_hash()`), with the login and the password posted by the user trying to log in, than the one you used to store the password in the database, except you don't store the result, but compare it with the hashed password stored in the database. If the password matches, it's OK. If it doesn't, the password (or login) is wrong. If you want an example, post the Java code used to store a new user and its hashed login in the database, and I'll try to adapt it to check a password.

Comment: I have given the code I used below. On the registration, I take the user name and encrypt and store in the database. I take the password and hash it and store in the database at that time. When user logs next time, I run a for loop for all users. Every user name is decrypted and checked with the user name entered by the user at the login. If the decrypted user name matches the entered user name, I check the hashed password. If the number of users are expected to be high, I store first 3 words in a separate field to filter out so that the loop will not take significant time.

Comment: This is a horrible way of doing. Why do you encrypt the user names? They shouldn't be secret. Only the password is. Anyway, why don't you encrypt the user name submitted, find the row which has this encrypted user name, and then check if the hashed password of this row matches with the hashed password stored in the row? Does the encryption algorithm produce non-deterministic outputs?

Comment: The necessity of user names to encrypt & store or store as unencrypted  depends on the situation. Storing them unencrypted tells an attacker which accounts are valid, eliminating half the break-in battle.

Comment: If you want something more secure, you'd better use a harder to break algorithm than MD5 instead of encrypting your user names. bcrypt, for example. And avoid uppercasing all the passwords before hashing them, which also makes it much easier to find a password. And using a different, random salt for every user, instead of a constant one.

Comment: I agree. In that case, how to check the credentials?

Comment: Buddhika, why in earth did you downvote JB Nizet's answer for that? Besides, if you've a problem/question related to your own code, just press `[Ask Question]` button on right top.

Comment: *How to check the credentials*. I already answered, thrice, to this question: apply the same algorithm than the one used to store the login and password, but instead of storing the result, compare it with what you have in the database row for this user.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I will post my issue as a separate Question. I tried, but failed to remove the downgrade.

Answer (score -1):

I store unencrypted first three characters of the user names in the database as a separate field. When a user enters the credentials, I retrieve all the entities matching to the first three characters of entered user name. I run a for loop where the decryption is done for each. If the decrypted one matches the entered user name, I check the hash for the password.

I use a dedicated library like Jasypt. Why reinvent the wheel.

IF the expected maximum number of users is not that large, we can simply avoid storing first few letters and straight-away go through all the records for the for loop.

This is Security Controller.

```
package com.divudi.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.jasypt.util.password.BasicPasswordEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.util.text.BasicTextEncryptor;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public SecurityController() {
}

public String encrypt(String word) {
    BasicTextEncryptor en = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    en.setPassword("health");
    try {
        return en.encrypt(word);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String hash(String word) {
    try {
        BasicPasswordEncryptor en = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
        return en.encryptPassword(word);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean matchPassword(String planePassword, String encryptedPassword) {
    BasicPasswordEncryptor en = new BasicPasswordEncryptor();
    return en.checkPassword(planePassword, encryptedPassword);
}

public String decrypt(String word) {
    BasicTextEncryptor en = new BasicTextEncryptor();
    en.setPassword("health");
    try {
        return en.decrypt(word);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }

    }
}
```

This is the methods when user enters the credentials.

```
private boolean checkUsers() {
    String temSQL;
    temSQL = "SELECT u FROM WebUser u WHERE u.retired = false";
    List<WebUser> allUsers = getFacede().findBySQL(temSQL);
    for (WebUser u : allUsers) {
        if (getSecurityController().decrypt(u.getName()).equalsIgnoreCase(userName)) {
            if (getSecurityController().matchPassword(passord, u.getWebUserPassword())) {
                setLoggedUser(u);
                setLogged(Boolean.TRUE);
                setActivated(u.isActivated());
                setRole(u.getRole());
                getMessageController().setDefLocale(u.getDefLocale());
                getMeController().createMenu();
                getWebUserBean().setLoggedUser(u);
                UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("Logged successfully");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hashing != Encryption. You've a major security problem there. Related: http://diovo.com/2009/02/wrote-your-own-encryption-algorithm-duh/ and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/is-my-developers-home-brew-password-security-right-or-wrong-and-why/

Comment: What I mean is that Hashing and Encryption is entirely different. Encrypted word can be decrypted when the key is available. But hashed word will never be decrypted again. That is one way encryption. Am I wrong? I use user names encrypted and passwrods hashed.